# faild to resolve: com.android.support:constraint:constraint-layout

Tags: android

when i want to add this line in build.gradle,throws an error.

```
Error:(26, 13) 
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:constraint:constraint-layout
```

please help me to resolve that.

Comment: You should add version `layout:1.0.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```